# Настройка проекта с Laravel

Tags: laravel

Установил Laravel через композер, в папку blog
Получаю урл, захожу `http://blog:8080/` - показывает просто структуру. 
И чтобы приложение запустилось, нужно ещё приписывать каталог public.
Как сделать, чтобы все работало, введя просто адрес `http://blog:8080/`?

Спасибо.

Comment: @TheOwl, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Есть два варианта:

1. В конфигурации сервера (Apache, Ngnix, Xampp) прописать виртуальный хост с путем в public директорию. В названии сервера прописать соответствующее имя и порт
2. Запустить с помощью команды artisan в командной строке:

   ```
   php artisan serve --host=blog --port=8080
   ```